# Repopulate input type=file in Rails when create/update fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form, a user can upload images as part of the form but if that form fails validation, all of those images are lost.

Is there a way to repopulate those fields with the images they've submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. For example, you can use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). It has built in functionality to solve this issue. Code snippet right from README:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <label>My Avatar</label>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
  </p>
```

As you can see there's a hidden field. Basically, CarrierWave saves a copy `avatar` between requests inside of `avatar_cache` field. On the form re-rendering it pulls image from the cache (if there's any). If you don't want to use CarrierWave, you could learn how to implement similar solution from it's sources.